# App sending information each minute in background

Tags: android, location

I've developed an Android app and I want to add the next feature:
Send each minute information to a web service, even if the app is in background mode. I'd like this feature works along the day.

I've tried with AlarmManager calling to a BroadcastReceiver  and the last one calling to LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate but it doesn't work very well, even the same code, works with different interval, depending on the device, if it's tablet o phone, and I don't know why.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with a service running at background. Probaqble you won't achieve "each one minute" because of Doze restrictions on newer Android releases

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work for me. Furthermore, I don't understand why the same app, it works every 1 min in one device and every 5 min in another(tablet/phone)

Comment: can be because the Android OS version. More recent versions are more aggresive with background work. Maybe you can batch and save it offline and then send all at once

Comment: I can't do that, because I want to send the location of the user each minute to my server, to display it in the app web on "real time"

Comment: I'm afraid that it won't be possible in Android. It is possible when the user is in the app (ie the app is on foreground), but impossible to achieve while in background, on a one-minute basis.

Comment: And... it's legal to do that?

Comment: Of course it's legal. I ask permission to the user, it's not an app for the store, it's for a company, to help to the deliveries

Comment: you can think of check-in every x minutes or every action, instead of doing it periodically

Answer (score 1):

Knowing better your use case now, I'm afraid to say no, it's not possible to achieve what you want (to make an action every 1minute in the background). Due to the (good) limitations in Doze, you simply can't do that, it will drain very fast the user's battery. For doing a repetitive task in a periodic way, you need the app to be in the foreground. You can acquire a WAKE_LOCK, but I think you don't want that, because of the battery drain too.

Your best option IMHO is changing the logic of the app, and recolect the position or whatever in response to events, for example, instead of doing it periodically

Comment: and could I trigger a event each minute? Can you give me an example or telling me the keywords to research? Thanks

Comment: @Juanjo The event can't be periodic. I'm referring on send the info to the server on some user actions. For example, if it's delivering a package, get its location when a delivery is done, or when is opening the deliveries list, r when opens the app, for example. Just examples

Comment: ah ok, I understand. I'll research about it. Thanks